# Attribute 'strict' is not allowed to appear in element 'csv:listBinding' in smooks1.4

Tags: mule

I am trying to read csv file using smooks1.4 . I want to check the field missmatch , for that in my smooks config file i am using  strict="true".but it is throwing

> error like this
>   cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute
>   'strict' is not allowed to appear in
>   element 'csv:listBinding'

this is my **smooks-config.xml** file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<smooks-resource-list xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd"
    xmlns:csv="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/csv-1.2.xsd">
    <csv:reader fields="firstName,lastName,welcome">

            <csv:listBinding beanId="customerList" class="example.Customer" strict="true"/>
         </csv:reader>
</smooks-resource-list>
```

**My smooks releated Jar files are**

```
  milyn-commons-1.4.jar

  milyn-smooks-core-1.4.jar

  milyn-smooks-csv-1.4.jar 

  milyn-smooks-javabean-1.4.jar

  milyn-smooks-templating-1.4.jar
```

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following URI for the csv namespace:

`http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/csv-1.3.xsd`

Also, strict is an attribute of csv:reader, not csv:listBinding.